# Shared Cassandra Session loses connection and app must be restarted

Tags: python, cassandra

I am working on a Flask web service which uses Cassandra as a datastore.

The web service is setup to use a shared session for Cassandra which, I have read, automatically handle connection pooling.

When I deploy the application, everything works fine for a period of time but after a certain amount of time the session loses all C* hosts in the cluster and refuses to attempt to reconnect.  It simply errors out with the message: `Unable to complete the operation against any hosts`.

What can I do to either have the session automatically attempt to reconnect to the cluster or detect that the session is broken so I can shut it down and create a new session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to create a new session.  Assuming you are using the [datastax python-driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver), the driver maintains a 'control connection' which subscribes to node up/down events.  If the control connection is lost, it will reconnect to another host in the cluster.   It would be useful to [turn on debug logging](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/python-driver/2.1/python-driver/reference/enablingDebugLevelLogging.html), which will reveal why the nodes in your cluster are being marked down.